# What size wire for 70 amp sub-panel to garage?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

What gauge wire is need to make a 150 to 200ft run for a 70amp subpanel? 
I’m putting a 70 amp sub panel in the gargare which has no service at all. Going to be running lights, garage opener and a few outlets.

Comment: How big is the garage (in square feet)?

Comment: There are many questions on the site already that address this.  I see 4 of them just in the "related" sidebar to the right.

Answer (score 2):

#3 copper will provide 70 amps at 240v with a 2.74% voltage drop or #1 aluminum at 2.83% drop at 200 feet.

[Source](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm)

Answer (score 2):

### Minimum *mandatory* wire size is based on the breaker rating

There is a mininum wire size which is *required* based on the circuit breaker rating.  **That size is #4 copper or #2 aluminum**.

You get this number by using a quality voltage drop calculator by specifying the breaker amperage and a wire length of 1 foot. e.g.

- 240V
- 3%
- 70A (the number on the breaker
- 1 foot (to keep it from upsizing for distance)

*By the way, if the circuit was 55A (breaker 60A) that would  be #6Cu/#4Al.*

### Be smart when you *optionally* upsize to reduce voltage drop

Over 100 feet of run, it's time to *think about* upsizing the wire to reduce voltage drop.  This is a matter of using a larger-than-required wire to minimize voltage sag at the far end.  **It's not mandatory**. **

However, the classic blunder is doing your voltage drop calculation based on the *breaker* number.  **Actually, you should be doing the voltage drop calc based on your computed loads**.

You specified lights (2A if that), garage door opener (10A very intermittently) and vaguely "some outlets", so inconsequential loads, maybe a 1500W heater or something.

I don't know about you, but I don't use a garage door opener *while* using a saw.  The lights are inconsequential.  So let's oversize this thing and pretend you're using *two* common 120/15A at max load of 12A, and you have been halfway intelligent about balancing - putting each load on opposite poles. so you dual 12@120 = 12@240.  Let's bump it to 20A for some headroom.  **Heck, let's bump it to 30A** just for chuckles.  Now we hit the voltage drop calc again.  This time, we say

- 240V
- 5% voltage drop
- 30A (the *typical* load we expect to use ordinarily, even this is exaggerated)
- 200' (our *actual* distance).

OK. The result is 6cu/4al with 2.29% drop, which is smaller than our "minimum mandatory" size above -- so we must use the minimum mandatory.

Final answer: **#4Cu or #2Al.**

---

**  unless your application is expected to cause *rather extreme* voltage sag, definitely not the case here. Some people think there's a "3%" requirement in the NEC. [Citation Needed].  Actually, NEC has an informational note that *suggests* upsizing to limit voltage drop to 3-5%  *based on actual loads* will provide reasonable efficiency of operation.  That's all it says, it's not a mandate. NEC 215.2(A)(4).